# how to write a rule query_string RewriteEngine

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

need of such http://example.net/tags/index.php?tag=anytag,
to make such http://example.net/tags/anytag
doing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^tag=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^tags/index.php$     /tags/$1     [NC,L,R=301]
```

not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want it just the other way round

```
RewriteRule ^/tags/(.*)$ /tags/index.php?tag=$1
```

[`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with test string `QUERY_STRING` is only used, when the input already contains a query string. If you want to rewrite some URL to another URL, you simply append the desired query string to the target URL.